# iOS - Creating photo slideshow

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I've made a simple photo slideshow for my app , the problem is my code does not repeat images after last image  again ! here is my code :

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {

    _button.hidden = YES;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(photoCounter) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


}


- (void)photoCounter {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.90];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:NO];
    [self updatePhoto];
    imageCount ++;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)updatePhoto {

    switch (imageCount) {

        case 0:
            _images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall1.jpg"];
            break;

        case 1:
            _images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall2.jpg"];
            break;
        case 2:
            _images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall3.jpg"];
            break;
        case 3:
            _images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall4.jpg"];
            break;
        case 4:
            _images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall5.jpg"];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove imageCount++ from photoCounter method and

```
- (void)updatePhoto 
{
    switch (imageCount) 
    {
        case 0:
            _images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall1.jpg"];
            break;
        case 1:
            _images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall2.jpg"];
            break;
        case 2:
            _images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall3.jpg"];
            break;
        case 3:
            _images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall4.jpg"];
            break;
        case 4:
            _images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall5.jpg"];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    imageCount ++;
    if (imageCount > 4)
        imageCount = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe better

```
- (void)updatePhoto {
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"wall%d", imageCount];
    _images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    (imageCount > 4) ? imageCount = 0 : imageCount++;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In the function `- (void)photoCounter`... instead of `imageCount++`, try putting

```
if(imageCount > 4){ 
    imageCount = 0;
} else { 
    imageCount++;
}
```